# is it possible to return "if condition satisfies return a list else return an error message" using a java method

Tags: java

I know that in Java a method can return only one return type... But if there is any possiblity to this, kindly let me know. From the below method I am trying to return a list if condition satisfies else i am trying to return an error message.

Here is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getcompanies", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List<CompanyMaster> getCompanies(@RequestBody UserDetails user) {
    String OrgLoginId = user.getOrgLoginId();
    String password = user.getuPassword();
    String checkLoginId = null;
    String uPassword = null;
    String encPassword = null;
    String loginId = null;
    String checkAuthorized = null;
    //  String loginId=userService.getLoginId(OrgLoginId);
    List<Object[]> CheckIdPassword = userService.checkLoginId(OrgLoginId);
    List<Object[]> results = CheckIdPassword;
    for (Object[] obj : results) {
        checkLoginId = obj[0].toString();
        if (null == obj[1]) {
            uPassword = "";
        } else {
            uPassword = obj[1].toString();
        }
        loginId = obj[2].toString();
    }
    checkAuthorized = loginId.substring(0, 3);
    if (null != password) {
        MD5 md5 = new MD5();
        encPassword = md5.getPassword(password);
    }
    if (checkLoginId == null) {
        return "Incorrect loginId..Please enter valid loginId";
    } else if (encPassword.equals(uPassword)) {
        if (checkAuthorized.equals("STE")) {
            List<CompanyMaster> companyList = userService.getCompanyList(OrgLoginId);
            return companyList;
        } else {
            return "You are not Authorized";
        }
    } else {
        return "Incorrect Password";
    }
```

Comment: No, but you could create a new class which contains both the `list` and a `String` field - whichever is not null wins.  Or throw an Exception

Comment: Why not *throw* an exception where you would return the error string?

Comment: You shouldn't be using MD5 in 2020; that hash has been broken for sixteen years!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a new presenter Class which contains **List** and **status of type String** and change the return type of   *getCompanies* method to presenter class like

```
public CompaniesPresenter getCompanies()
```

And your CompaniesPresenter class should look like

```
    public class CompaniesPresenter {
    private List<CompanyMaster> companyMaster;
    private string status;

//default constructor
public CompaniesPresenter(){

    }

//parameterized constructor to return only string in exception case

public CompaniesPresenter(Stirng status){
        this.status = status;
    }

//parametirized constructor to return success case
public CompaniesPresenter(List<CompanyMaster> companyMaster, Stirng status){
        this.companyMaster = companyMaster;
        this.status = status;
    }

    //getters and setters
    }
```

This is how your updated method lokks like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getcompanies", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public CompaniesPresenter getCompanies(@RequestBody UserDetails user) {
        String OrgLoginId = user.getOrgLoginId();
        String password = user.getuPassword();
        String checkLoginId = null;
        String uPassword = null;
        String encPassword = null;
        String loginId = null;
        String checkAuthorized = null;
        //  String loginId=userService.getLoginId(OrgLoginId);
        List<Object[]> CheckIdPassword = userService.checkLoginId(OrgLoginId);
        List<Object[]> results = CheckIdPassword;
        for (Object[] obj : results) {
            checkLoginId = obj[0].toString();
            if (null == obj[1]) {
                uPassword = "";
            } else {
                uPassword = obj[1].toString();
            }
            loginId = obj[2].toString();
        }
        checkAuthorized = loginId.substring(0, 3);
        if (null != password) {
            MD5 md5 = new MD5();
            encPassword = md5.getPassword(password);
        }
        if (checkLoginId == null) {
            return new CompaniesPresenter("Incorrect loginId..Please enter valid loginId");

        } else if (encPassword.equals(uPassword)) {
            if (checkAuthorized.equals("STE")) {
                List<CompanyMaster> companyList = userService.getCompanyList(OrgLoginId);
                return new CompaniesPresenter(companyList,"success");
            } else {
                return new CompaniesPresenter("You are not Authorized");
            }
        } else {
            return new CompaniesPresenter("Incorrect Password");
        }
```

This is not tested please make sure for any compilation errors

Answer (score 3):

Yes its possible, create a custom Exception say 'MyAppException' and throw that exception with the error message you want.

Write your logic in a try{}catch block and throw the exception in catch so that the response has the error message

```
public List<CompanyMaster> getCompanies(@RequestBody UserDetails user) throws MyAppppException
{
    try
    {
        //your logic which throws error
        return companyList;
    }
    catch( final MyAppException we )
    {
        throw new MyAppException("User not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Refer this link
https://www.codejava.net/java-core/exception/how-to-create-custom-exceptions-in-java

Answer (score 0):

vavr's Either class would be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of custom exception is most reasonable solution. However, creating custom exception for just one case is not ideal always. 
Another solution is to return empty List from your method, check if the List is empty in your servlet (or wherever you are invoking this method from), and show error message there.
It seems like you want to return multiple error messages for different cases. In this case, custom exception is recommended solution. If you don't like custom exceptions, you can return `List<Object>` and populate error message as the first element in the list. In the place where this List is obtained, check if the first element is `instanceOf` `String` or `CompanyMaster`. Based on what it is, you can perform your operations. This is a weird but possible solution (only if you don't like custom exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the problem first. You are mixing two things here, first authorization, does the user has correct privileges to get company details, second giving the company details itself. Let's understand the first problem when a user tries to access "/getcompanies" endpoint will you let him in if does not have access, in REST world your security model should take care of it. I would use spring security to achieve this. My recommendation would be to explore on "interceptor" and solve the problem of invalid user. This will make your other problem easy as your "/getcompanies" endpoint can focus only on getting the details and return it (SRP).